# How can I determine which variable to use for a defined function in python

Tags: python

I have defined this function :

```
def xintegral(x,k,z,xdot):
     f=np.exp((x-xdot)**2*k/(2*z)*1j)
     return f
```

And I want to insert this function in the place of func to this process:

```
def simpson(func,mini,maxi,N): 
     sum=0   
     h=(maxi-mini)/N 
     even=mini+2*h
     odd=mini+h 

     for i in range(N//2-1):  
          sum+=func(even)*2
          even+=2*h
     for i in range(N//2): 
          sum+=func(odd)*4
          odd+=2*h
     sum=(sum+(func(mini)+func(maxi)))*h/3 
     return sum
```

I want to use as a func the xintegral with variable the xdot. So I tried to write it like that : simpson(xintegral(x,k,z,xdot),mini,maxi,N) 
but I want the variable to be the xdot. The variables odd,mini,maxi can replace  xdot? How can I do that?

Comment: Please fix the indentation on this. And are you suggesting that you want `func` to be some variable function to be called i.e. `func` might be something other than `xintegral`?

Comment: I changed the indentation .Sorry for that. Generally I'd like func to be a variable function like math.sin, etc etc. But in my case I want to use that definition for func=xintegral.

Comment: I don't understand. if `func = xintegral`, what would `func(even)` look like for `xintegral`?

Comment: That s the problem. I want the func(even) for the xintegral to be the xintegral with xdot=even.

Comment: Like math.sin is a function of x, I want xintegral with constants  x,k,z to be a function of xdot to use it in the simpson definition to insert values in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with partial application. This will create a function `p_xintegral` that will take a single argument. That single argument will be assigned to `xdot` with in `xintegral` and `x`, `y`, and `z` are determined at the time you do the partial application:

```
from functools import partial

p_xintegral = partial(xintegral, x, y, z)
```

So you should then be able to call `simpson(p_xintegral, mini, maxi, N)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. Otherwise your f is not a function

```
def xintegral(x,k,z,xdot):
     f=lambda j:np.exp((x-xdot)**2*k/(2*z)*1j)
     return f
```